# Build and run an executable locally with Conan

Tags: cmake, conan

Say I have a simple hello world project in CMake that creates a binary under `bin`.
I build it with Conan using [the latest CMake module](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/cmake.html).

In the `conanfile.py`, is this `package` method enough to announce the executable?

```py
    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()
```

Then, if I want to build the project and run the executable locally, but in Conan's context, which commands should I type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package method you've defined will use the installation structure defined by `cmake.install()` to define the package structure. For example, if your `cmake.install()` method installs binaries to the `bin` directory, the `bin` directory will be present in the package folder in your conan cache, i.e. `~/.conan/data/<package>/<version>/<user>/<channel>/package/<package_id>/bin`.

This alone is enough to run the executable locally - you can execute it from the above path, put it onto your PATH - whatever you need. It's not convenient though. To add some convenience, you can use the `VirtualRunEnv` generator to consume executables. To illustrate with `cmake`:

```
$ conan install cmake/3.22.4@ --build=missing -g VirtualRunEnv
```

This will install cmake 3.22.4 into your local cache, and generate the following files in your cwd:

```
.
├── conanrunenv-release-x86_64.sh
├── conanrun.sh
├── deactivate_conanrunenv-release-x86_64.sh
└── deactivate_conanrun.sh
```

You can use this in the same way you would a python virtual environment:

```
$ source conanrun.sh
$ which cmake
/home/user/.conan/data/cmake/3.22.4/_/_/package/5c09c752508b674ca5cb1f2d327b5a2d582866c8/bin/cmake
```

And to restore the environment:

```
$ source deactivate_conanrun.sh
Restoring environment
$ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
```

The second method is to use the `deploy` generator:

```
$ conan install cmake/3.22.4@ --build=missing -g deploy
```

This will grab `cmake` and all of it's dependencies from the conan cache and dump them to your cwd. After running this command, the directory looks like the following:

```
.
├── cmake
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── ccmake
│   │   ├── cmake
│   │   ├── cpack
│   │   └── ctest
│   ├── licenses
│   │   └── Copyright.txt
│   └── share
│       ├── aclocal
│       ├── bash-completion
│       ├── cmake-3.22
│       ├── emacs
│       └── vim
├── deploy_manifest.txt
└── openssl
    ├── bin
    │   ├── c_rehash
    │   └── openssl
    ├── include
    │   └── openssl
    ├── lib
    │   ├── cmake
    │   ├── libcrypto.a
    │   └── libssl.a
    └── licenses
        └── LICENSE
```

You can then move this wherever you need to and put it on your system PATH if you so desire. The same principle would apply to your package - create the recipe in the local cache, and use generators to consume it.

To illustrate:

1. Place your package in the conan cache

```
$ conan create .
```

2. Consume it using `VirtualRunEnv`

```
$ conan install mypkg/0.1.0@user/channel --build=missing -g VirtualRunEnv
```

3. Consume it using `deploy`

```
$ conan install mypkg/0.1.0@user/channel --build=missing -g deploy
```

Instead of issuing `conan install` commands above, you can also list your package as a requirement in a `conanfile.txt` or `conanfile.py` for a consumer package, i.e. for a `conanfile.py`:

```py
def requirements(self):
    self.requires(mypkg/0.1.0)
    self.requires(someotherpkg/1.2.0)
```

And then you can use the virtual environment generators to collect environment information for all dependencies. In the directory containing the `conanfile.py`:

```
$ conan install . -g VirtualRunEnv
```

Hope this helps.

References:

- [VirtualRunEnv generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/env/virtualrunenv.html)
- [deploy generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/deploy.html)
- [Mastering Conan Virtual Environments](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/virtualenv.html#virtual-environment-generator)
- [virtualrunenv generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/virtualrunenv.html) (deprecated, I believe)
- [Conan generators](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators.html)

Comment: It helps a lot, thanks. How about the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Don't you need to set them to run the binary directly from the package directory? If so, then the `VirtualRunEnv` is the "right" solution?

Comment: In your `VirtualRunEnv` example, it works fine with `cmake`. But I don't get a `conanrun.sh` produced when I install the current project with: `conan install -g VirtualRunEnv --build=missing .`

Comment: Also, did you use `conan create` to produce the package under `.conan/data`?

Comment: Yes, the package can be put in the conan cache using `conan create`. You can also do it manually using [`conan export-pkg`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/export-pkg.html), after having executed `conan install`, `conan build` and `conan package`. `conan create` is the easy way to do this though.

Comment: The method described above only works as a consumer. When you run `conan install .`, you're installing and and creating the generators necessary to consume your dependencies, but not the package you're yet to build (your package). For your use case, appending the `-g VirtualRunEnv` flag won't do what you want it to - if anything, it will generate the files for your packages upstream dependencies. You'll need to place your package in the conan cache, using `conan create`, and _then_ you can consume it with: `$ conan install mypkg/0.1.0@user/channel -g VirtualRunEnv`

Comment: @VictorPaléologue yes, if your application requires shared libs then the `deploy` generator may not be appropriate, and the `VirtualRunEnv` generator is the "right" solution. If your application compiles the static libs, then It's neither here nor there. Also, I've updated my answer to be more complete.